# Is the class extending ClientBehaviorBase can be considered as an injection target?

Tags: jsf-2.2, mojarra, glassfish-4.1.1

The bean is defined to be as simple as follows:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ConfirmBean {

    private String confirmMsg;

    public ConfirmBean(){
        confirmMsg = "Are you sure you want to delete this file ?";
    }   

   // getters & setters           
}
```

And the class inheriting the `ClientBehaviorBase`

```
@FacesBehavior(value = "confirm")
public class ConfirmDeleteBehavior extends ClientBehaviorBase {

    @Inject
    ConfirmBean confirmBean;
    //@Inject
    //ConfirmEJBBean confirmEJBBean;
    //@EJB
    //ConfirmEJBBean confirmEJBBean;

    @Override
    public String getScript(ClientBehaviorContext behaviorContext) {
        return "return confirm('"+confirmBean.getConfirmMsg()+"');";
    }
}
```

with the taglib file-

```
    <namespace>http://www.custom.tags/jsf/delete</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>confirmDelete</tag-name>
        <behavior>
            <behavior-id>confirm</behavior-id>
        </behavior>
    </tag>
```

with an entry as `context-param` in `web.xml`-

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/taglib/delete.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and accessing this custom tag in the front layer-

```
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="done">
                <b:confirmDelete/>
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
```

I am using `Glassfish` application server `4.1.1` with `Mojarra 2.2.12` version being used internally.

I got a `NPE` here-

[image]

Comment: Your tagging btw kind of suggests it works in MyFaces (due to the added Mojarra tag) and e.g. in JBoss (due to the GlassFish tag). At least that is how I always read tags...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so much that the extending the class makes it not eligable for injection it is that the `@FacesBehaviour` is annotation does not make it a  target of injection. A little googling told me this: [In JSF 2.2 it is not a target for injection, in 2.3 it is](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/jsf2-160102150453/95/jsf-23-new-features-29-638.jpg?cb=1451747353).

OmniFaces added support for injection in [FacesConverter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/FacesConverter)s and [FacesValidator](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/FacesValidator)s to be used with jsf 2.2 but not the FacesBehaviour.

See also:

- http://www.omnifaces-fans.org/2015/11/jsf-23-converters-validators-and.html